# Is there a way of limiting the depth of the trace generated by xdebug?

Tags: php, trace, xdebug

The question says it all, really.

I am trying to figure out why a php app is misbehaving, but the sheer amount of data thrown at me by xdebug makes it hard to understand the flow.

If I could set the depth of the trace such that any call more than x levels deep was skipped, then it would be easier to understand what was happening. Any ideas how to make xdebug do this, or is there an alternative tool I can use?

Comment: *How* do you trace? *How* do you look at the trace? Normally [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) should make it easy for you to filter depth.

Comment: I look at the trace as a text file. I've used kcachegrind before, but I haven't looked at this feature. Maybe I'll look again.

Comment: KCachegrind is a visualization tool for Xdebug **profiler**. We are talking about Xdebug **function tracing** .

Answer (score 2):

Xdebug's function/execution tracing to file does currently not support this, and Xdebug's stacktraces always also show the whole stack I've just added a feature request to the issue tracker for it: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=722

Derick

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Xdebug where to start and stop the function tracing by calling [functions](https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) `xdebug_start_trace()` and `xdebug_stop_trace()` in the code.

With Xdebug version 2.4 or higher, you can also limit Xdebug to only trace execution of some functions by calling [function](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions) `xdebug_start_function_monitor( array $list_of_functions_to_monitor )`. The array contains the list of functions you want to trace.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap trick:

Given a trace file, *file_name* you can use:

```
grep -E '[[:digit:]][[:space:]]{,n}->' file_name
```

with *n* = 2*L* + 1 to only show function calls with a depth of *L*.

So for example

```
grep -E '[[:digit:]][[:space:]]{,3}->' file_name
```

Will give you just the top level call.

[image]